# Dynamic ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that dynamically creates an element with `ngClick` handler and appends it to the directive element:

```
app.directive('truncate', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            textStr: '=',
            truncLength: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.open = false;

            scope.more = function() {
                console.log('hello');
            }

            scope.less = function() {
                var outputEle = angular.element('<span>' + scope.textStr.substring(0, scope.truncLength) + '<a data-ng-click="more()"> more...</a>' + '</span>');
                $compile(outputEle, scope);
                element.append(outputEle);
            }
            scope.less();
        }
    }
}]);
```

The dynamic element is being added but dynamic `ngClick` (defined inside the less function) is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation part is wrong. It should be

```
var outputEle = angular.element('<span>' + scope.textStr.substring(0, scope.truncLength) + '<a data-ng-click="more()"> more...</a>' + '</span>');
$compile(outputEle)(scope);
element.append(outputEle);
```

Note that `$compile(outputEle)` returns linking function, which you use next to connect DOM element to the `scope`.